# CakePHP 3.0 Group Two Queries

Tags: sql, join, union, cakephp-3.0

Still new to cakePHP, and still a bit slow with SQL...

I've managed to use cakephp's Query Builder to refine my query, almost where I want it. I've tried using various combinations of ->group and ->select, but I can't seem to get these two queries combined properly. Can anyone offer a clue or a new (more appropriate) direction?

My Desired Query:

```
SELECT
    accounts.id,
    accounts.account_name,
    account_credit_id,
    SUM(credit - debit)
FROM 
    (SELECT 
    account_credit_id,
    credit,
    debit    
    FROM transactions
    UNION
    SELECT 
    account_credit_id,
    credit,
    debit    
    FROM splits)
AS temp
INNER JOIN accounts
ON account_credit_id=accounts.id
WHERE accounts.account_term_id = 3
GROUP BY account_credit_id 
;
```

Controller (This is a mess and not working)  :

```
    $expense_balances = $this->Transactions->find('all')
        ->contain(['AccountCredits'])
        ->where(['AccountCredits.account_term_id ' => 3]) //Only Expense Accounts
        ->group(['account_credit_id'])
        ->select(['total' => 'sum(credit - debit)' , 'account_credit_id' , 'account_name' => 'AccountCredits.account_name' ])   ;
    $split_expense_balances = $this->Transactions->Splits->find('all')
        ->contain(['Accounts'])
        ->where(['Accounts.account_term_id ' => 3]) //Only Expense Accounts
        ->group(['account_credit_id'])
        ->select(['total' => 'sum(credit - debit)' , 'account_credit_id' ,  'account_name' => 'Accounts.account_name' ])    ;

    $all_balances = $expense_balances->union($split_expense_balances)
            ->group(['account_credit_id']);

    debug($all_balances->toArray());
```

Debug (You can see that the records are grouped on 'account_credit_id' but there are two sets of groups — one set from each table):

```
[
(int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Transaction) {

    'total' => '-72.5',
    'account_credit_id' => (int) 4,
    'account_name' => 'Pets',
    '[new]' => false,
    '[accessible]' => [
        '*' => true
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'Transactions'

},
(int) 1 => object(App\Model\Entity\Transaction) {

    'total' => '-80',
    'account_credit_id' => (int) 5,
    'account_name' => 'Groceries',
    '[new]' => false,
    '[accessible]' => [
        '*' => true
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'Transactions'

},
(int) 2 => object(App\Model\Entity\Transaction) {

    'total' => '-389.44998931884766',
    'account_credit_id' => (int) 2,
    'account_name' => 'Dining',
    '[new]' => false,
    '[accessible]' => [
        '*' => true
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'Transactions'

},
(int) 3 => object(App\Model\Entity\Transaction) {

    'total' => '-118.77000045776367',
    'account_credit_id' => (int) 4,
    'account_name' => 'Pets',
    '[new]' => false,
    '[accessible]' => [
        '*' => true
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'Transactions'

},
(int) 4 => object(App\Model\Entity\Transaction) {

    'total' => '-98.91999816894531',
    'account_credit_id' => (int) 5,
    'account_name' => 'Groceries',
    '[new]' => false,
    '[accessible]' => [
        '*' => true
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'Transactions'

}
```

]

What I am trying to achieve (grouping by 'account_credit_id' and summing the totals):

```
[
(int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Transaction) {

    'total' => '-191.27',
    'account_credit_id' => (int) 4,
    'account_name' => 'Pets',
    '[new]' => false,
    '[accessible]' => [
        '*' => true
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'Transactions'

},
(int) 1 => object(App\Model\Entity\Transaction) {

    'total' => '-178.92',
    'account_credit_id' => (int) 5,
    'account_name' => 'Groceries',
    '[new]' => false,
    '[accessible]' => [
        '*' => true
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'Transactions'

},
(int) 2 => object(App\Model\Entity\Transaction) {

    'total' => '-389.44998931884766',
    'account_credit_id' => (int) 2,
    'account_name' => 'Dining',
    '[new]' => false,
    '[accessible]' => [
        '*' => true
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'Transactions'

},
```

]

Comment: Anybody still interested? I was able to build the proper SQL query, and added it above

Comment: "Keep tryin, kiddo"...

Comment: Good job... sorry I interrupted a perfectly good conversation you are having with yourself :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why struggle? Cakephp's documentation states that you might be better off executing complex queries directly. So I did!

```
    $expense_balances = $connection->execute(
    'SELECT
        accounts.id,
        accounts.account_name,
        account_credit_id,
        SUM(credit - debit)
    FROM 
        (SELECT 
        account_credit_id,
        credit,
        debit    
        FROM transactions
        UNION
        SELECT 
        account_credit_id,
        credit,
        debit    
        FROM splits)
    AS temp
    INNER JOIN accounts
    ON account_credit_id=accounts.id
    WHERE accounts.account_term_id = 3
    GROUP BY account_credit_id '
    )
    ->fetchAll('assoc');
```